# Ubuntu installation dotted text display

Tags: 12.04, installation, video, ati, intel

I'm new to linux and to askubuntu.com.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop PC and at first there's the black screen. This is solved by the `nomodeset` option only the next problem I encounter is I get a graphical interface but it's displayed in a strange way, the colors are off, the top bar is displayed in 2 solid colors, no icons or anything and the text in the menu displays as dots, looks a bit like braille making it impossible to install.

I'm on a Intel i5-750 with a ATi FireGL v7700 video card.

I couldn't find anything on google about it, I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. I installed Ubuntu using the Alternate CD. After that Ubuntu would start up properly graphics issues so I started up in Recovery Mode, un-installed the video drivers, then booted with `nomodeset` and installed the latest drivers for ATI graphics cards. Now it works.

Hope it will help somebody.